# Invoking rake task for specific environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rake

Hello I'm writing a deploy script(rake task) for my mini project. And I have this part when I invoke the db seed :

```
Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
```

And also compiling assets :

```
Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
```

So I was wondering is there a way to invoke these tasks in production environment like you would do from a console like this :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, you can do as :

```
[arup@app (master)]$ rails g task my_namespace my_task1
      create  lib/tasks/my_namespace.rake
[arup@app (master)]$ cat lib/tasks/my_namespace.rake
namespace :my_namespace do
  desc "TODO"
  task my_task1: :environment do
  end
end
[arup@app (master)]$
```

Now see the Rakefile is ready for you.

Just open the `Rakefile` you just created, and define your tasks.

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  task my_task1: :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
    Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
  end
end
```

Hints is [2.10 Custom Rake Tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. When you are calling a Rake task programmatically like that, there's no good way to change the current 'environment' value. You can actually shell out to a `system "RAILS_ENV=production rake ...."`.  I think that's pretty much your only good option.

Comment: @jrochkind It seems it will work - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/test-rake-tasks-like-a-boss and http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/systems/automation.html ..

Comment: okay, if it works for you, that's cool. There's nothing I see in the code example which changes the Rails 'environment' setting, which I thought was what you needed, but, if you've got what you need, great!